# Zend Route Regex and invalid controller

Tags: zend-framework, routes

php i have method to add routes:

```
    public function addRoutes()
            {
                $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
                $redirect = $front->getRouter();
                $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex( 
                                                          "p\/(a-zA-Z0-9)\.htm",
                                                         array(
                                                         'controller'=>'page',
                                                         'action'=>'index',
                                                          1=>'ja.htm'
                                                          ),
                                                         array( 1 => 'page_name')
                        );
                $route2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex("(a-zA-Z0-9)\.html",
                        array('controller'=>'page',
                            'action'=>'index',
                            1=>'ja.html'),
                        array(1=>'page_name'));
                $redirect->addRoute('pages',$router);
                $redirect->addRoute('hmtmled',$route2);
               $front->setRouter($redirect);


            }
```

I tried to enter url like: p/ja.htm but i get error: Invalid controller specified (p). I know its for reason of default route, but how to change that?

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the slash, so does it work if you regex pattern is just `p/(a-zA-Z0-9)\.htm`?

Comment: Your pattern accepts only a _single_ alphanum char after the `p/`. Don't you need the following instead (note additional `+` qualifier): `p/(a-zA-Z0-9)+\.htm`

Comment: even if my pattern is p/(a-zA-Z0-9)+\.htm i get same error, even with options like p/(\w+\d+)\.htm still fails,so i don't think its regexp fault

Comment: Is that method part of your `Bootstrap` class? If so, are you sure it is being run? Remember, the `Bootstrap` methods that get called automatically are those of the form `_initXXX()` (note the leading underscore).

Comment: ok my solution is change regexp as Tim Fountain suggested and renaminh method as suggested David Weinraub suggested, thanks guys, sorry for not notifing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that method part of your `Bootstrap` class? If so, are you sure it is being run? Remember, the `Bootstrap` methods that get called automatically are those of the form `_initXXX()` (note the leading underscore).

Also, as @Tim Fountain astutely notes in the comments, the regex needs to be:

```
p/([0-9A-Za-z]+)\.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to remove the default routes:

> //excerpt from ZF reference **24.5.4. Default Routes**... If you do
>   not want this particular default route in your routing schema, you may
>   override it by creating your own 'default' route (i.e., storing it
>   under the name of 'default') or removing it altogether by using
>   removeDefaultRoutes():

```
// Remove any default routes
$router->removeDefaultRoutes();
```